# ERROR:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type...but this dictionary requires a model item of type..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to programming and I'm having some issues when i'm trying to run the program. I keep on getting this error:"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'DCMS.Models.Projects.Project', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DCMS.ViewModels.ProjectDetailsViewModel'".
 This is my Controller:

```
        public ActionResult GetProjectView(int id)
            {
                var projectDataAccess = new ProjectDataAccess();
                var project = projectDataAccess.GetProject(id);
                if (project == null) return PartialView("Error");
                return View("ProjectView", project);
            }
```

This is part of my View:

```
@model DCMS.ViewModels.ProjectListViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var project in Model.ProjectList)
    {
        <div class="accordion-container">
            <h3 class="accordion-header">
                @Html.ActionLink(project.Client.ClientName + " / " + project.ProjectName + " / " + project.ProjectNum ?? "<null>", "GetProjectView", new {id = project.Id})<span class="right">@Html.ActionLink("View Details", "GetProjectView", new {id = project.Id})</span>
            </h3>
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <table class="accordion-details">
                    <tr class="accordion-evenrow">
                        <td class="accordion-header-column">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => project.ProjectStatus)
                        </td>
                        <td class="accordion-value-column">
                            @project.ProjectStatus
                        </td>
```

This is the ProjectView:

```
@model DCMS.ViewModels.ProjectDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 id="breadcrumbs">@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Project") > @(Model.Project.ProjectName ?? "<null>")/@Model.Project.ProjectNum </h2>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="projectTabs" style="display:none;">
        <li><a href="#projectdetails">Project Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Client Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vendor">Vendor Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#status">Status</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 style="margin:1px; font-size:20px;">@Model.Project.ProjectName /@Model.Project.ProjectNum</h2>
    <div id="projectdetails">
        @Html.Partial("Partial/EditProject")
    </div>
    <div id="pricing">
        @Html.Partial("Partial/Pricing")
    </div>
    <div id="status">
        @Html.Partial("Partial/ProjectStatus")
    </div>
    <div id="vendor">
        @Html.Partial("Partial/VendorPricing")
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#projectTabs").show();
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

</script>
```

How can i pass the project which is of type Project to the View which is of type ProjectDetailsViewModel?
I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: You cant. They need to be the same type.

Comment: The ProjectDetailsViewModel has a Property that is of type Project... so how can i pass the project to the View?sorry but I'm very new to programming...Thanks.

Comment: ProjectDetailsViewModel  c = new ProjectDetailsViewModel  () ; c.Project =  project ; return View("ProjectView", ProjectDetailsViewModel );

Comment: A view model should not contain a property which is a data model. And again, they need to be the **same**. Either pass an instance of `ProjectDetailsViewModel` to the view, or make the view `@model Project`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I agree . But if the view is only for display purpose and only few values to [projectname and number , like in this scenario and no change to the actual value] can we not use it ? [I know for this scenario ideally we can use viewbag] .

Comment: @FakeisMe, The fact OP has a `EditProject` partial suggests its not only for display (and in your previous comment it should have been `return View("ProjectView", c);`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I was asking generally not with respect to this scenario. Generally, if we have a view for display purpose alone and datamodel can direclty give us required data then can we not use it .? (yes return object i.e c , cannot edit the comment.)

Comment: @FakeisMe, If its for display only, then it not such an issue although a view model will give benefits such as `[Display]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Yes view model is very useful in such scenario. Thanks for answering !!! .

Comment: @FakeisMe:Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked perfectly for me!!!-BYG

Answer (score 0):

As the Error States,

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'DCMS.Models.Projects.Project', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'DCMS.ViewModels.ProjectDetailsViewModel'

ViewModel and the Model passed should be same.

```
public ActionResult GetProjectView(int id)
{
      ProjectDetailsViewModel _projectModel = new ProjectDetailsViewModel();
      var projectDataAccess = new ProjectDataAccess();
      var project = projectDataAccess.GetProject(id);
       _projectModel.Project = project ;
       if (project == null) return PartialView("Error");
       return View("ProjectView", _projectModel );
 }
```